# Wanting to stop subprocesses when all of them have finished running

Tags: python, bash

Currently I'm running a python script which runs all of the shell scripts inside a certain directory. I'm having trouble because the process doesn't stop even when all the other scripts have finished running.

This is my code

```
for file in dirs:
    if file.endswith(".sh"):
        filePath = os.getcwd() + "/arrayscripts/" + file
        arrayProcess = subprocess.Popen([filePath, delay, loop, userID], shell=False)
```

Is there any way I can check to see whether or not all of these scripts have finished running and so I can kill arrayProcess?

Previously I tried using the delay and loop variables to find out how long the script would run and then add one second to the result. I then used this result to tell my script to sleep until the script had finished and then kill arrayProcess. Apparently this isn't a good way to go about doing this because there can sometimes be unexpected delays/ lags and so I should be using a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Popen.wait()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) to wait for the processes to terminate.
The best option would be to store all the processes in a list and after starting all of them just `wait()` until they terminate. You should not have to kill them manually (if the scripts exit on their own).